# How union initialization works?

Tags: c, initialization, unions

The problem is came from one exercise question on my C book.

*07. From the compiler's point of view, why does this code fail?*

```c
union id { char name[4]; long number; } var = { "Tom", 1 };
```

I know that too many initialization value make error.

But my question is **why it goes to error**.

Is the C compiler just counts the number of values whether it is one? Or the C compiler works like accepting first one value, and if there are other values returning error?

Maybe these two concepts look similar, but these are not the same. If you understood, please help me by answer.

Comment: `why it goes to error.` - because C standard says so, and according to C standard, such program is ill-formed. There is no point second-guessing the compiler and figuring out how it is implemented.

Comment: GCC gives a warning *"excess elements in union initializer"*, not an error. As such it is "ignoring" the excess initializer elements.

Comment: Do you worry about implementation details of compiler?

Comment: Yeap. I'm talking about implementation details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for initialization are in C 2018 6.7.9. Initializers can have designators, such as `union id var = { .number = 1 };`, to explicitly initialize a particular union member by name. In the case you show, where there is no designator, paragraph 17 says:

> … When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union…

A consequence of this is that there is only one thing to initialize, the first named member of the union. There are no other candidates listed. This means, of the two initializers you show, `“Tom”` is used to initialize the member `name`, and `1` does not have anything to initialize. Even though there is another member in the union, the rules for initializing union members do not say to use any more initializers.

So the compiler complains because the `1` does not belong there.

Comment: Thank you very much! It might be the answer I wanted.
Actually, I tried to discuss this with my professor but he asked me to get to know about this.
Sadly, I failed google about this, and uploaded my first question here thinking 'if I ask hear...'
Now I know that was good choice. Thank you sir!